# Distributing the hours from master table to all the matching values in reference table using excel formula or power queries

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerquery

My master table contains below data

| RESOURCE NAME | SKILL GROUP | PROJECT | COST PER HOUR | CAPACITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 12.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 11.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 3 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 12.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 4 | Report Testing | Project 2 | 12.0 | 200.0 |
| Resource 5 | CICD and Devops | Project 3 | 11.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 6 | Performance Testing | Project 1 | 12.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 7 | Automation Testing | Project 2 | 10.0 | 250.0 |
| Resource 8 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 12.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 9 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 11.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 10 | Cloud Testing | Project 1 | 11.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 11 | Report Testing | Project 3 | 12.0 | 800.0 |

and my references table has got these entries

| RESOURCE NAME | SKILL GROUP | PROJECT | DEMAND | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 2 | 900.0 |  |
| Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 300.0 |  |
| Resource 3 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 400.0 |  |
| Resource 1 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 200.0 |  |
| Resource 4 | CICD and Devops | Project 3 | 300.0 |  |
| Resource 5 | Performance Testing | Project 2 | 900.0 |  |
| Resource 6 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 200.0 |  |
| Resource 2 | Cloud Testing | Project 2 | 900.0 |  |
| Resource 7 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 400.0 |  |
| Resource 8 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 800.0 |  |
| Resource 9 | Report Testing | Project 2 | 900.0 |  |
| Resource 10 | Pipeline Testing | Project 1 | 600.0 |  |
| Resource 11 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 700.0 |  |
| Resource 10 | Performance Testing | Project 2 | 900.0 |  |
| Resource 11 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 250.0 |  |

What I am trying to achieve here to distribute my capacity hours given in the master table to all the matching records in reference table.

**For example:**
In master table for Resource 10 total capacity is 900 hours and he has been allocated to 2 different projects in reference table, so his capacity columns in the reference table will be updated and total capacity should be distributed to 450 each and in future if he get assigned more projects then his total capacity will be distributed among all the entries matches to Resource 10. Same for other matching Resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 365:

```
=XLOOKUP([@[Resource Name]],MasterTable[Resource Name],MasterTable[Capacity])/COUNTIF([Resource Name],[@[Resource Name]])
```

[image]

for the first few entries.

---

I'm not sure if this is really what you want, but this is an example where the last entry is adjusted to make all entries for the same resource exact to one decimal place

```
=LET(totcap,XLOOKUP([@[Resource Name]],MasterTable[Resource Name],MasterTable[Capacity]),
count,COUNTIF([Resource Name],[@[Resource Name]]),
roundcap,ROUND(totcap/count,1),
IF(ROW()<MAX(IF([@[Resource Name]]=[Resource Name],ROW([Resource Name]))),roundcap,totcap-roundcap*(count-1)))
```

[image]

Here is the formula without let - horrible:

```
=IF(ROW()<MAX(IF([@[Resource Name]]=[Resource Name],ROW([Resource Name]))),ROUND(XLOOKUP([@[Resource Name]],MasterTable[Resource Name],MasterTable[Capacity])/COUNTIF([Resource Name],[@[Resource Name]]),1),XLOOKUP([@[Resource Name]],MasterTable[Resource Name],MasterTable[Capacity])-ROUND(XLOOKUP([@[Resource Name]],MasterTable[Resource Name],MasterTable[Capacity])/COUNTIF([Resource Name],[@[Resource Name]]),1)*(COUNTIF([Resource Name],[@[Resource Name]])-1))
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, it works fine until the results are not in decimal, I want to have exact matching with distributed hours vs total capacity. For example if we add 3 records then it results in decimal values.

Comment: Do you mean, if you had three entries for resource 1. then you would get 266.666...? You could display it to one decimal place as 266.7, but then the three numbers as displayed would add up to 800.1 not 800?

Comment: yes exactly I was referring same, how could I handle this situation as on the basis of this (hours) my cost will be calculated which will differ in actuals

Comment: So just to check, in this case you would want the capacities to be 266.7, 266.7 and 266.6 ? It could be done, but quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: I started getting `#NAME?` error using this solution. Is the range given is correct?

Comment: It's fine on my setup. Only major change is using Let, but if you can use xlookup you should be able to use Let.

Comment: I am using office 365 app for enterprise and LET function is not coming up after "=", what could be the reason?

Comment: You could be on semi-annual release, in which it looks as though Let only appeared in July. Of course you can do it without let, but it would be a pretty long formula https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/semi-annual-enterprise-channel

Comment: Have added the formula without Let.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you, in powerquery

Load Master table as a query. File .. close and load to ... create connection only. Name it **MasterTable**

Load Reference table (without the capacity column) into powerquery
Right click Resource Name, group by, [x] advanced
For the first row, use operation count rows
For the second row, use operation all rows
[image]

Expand the data using the arrows atop the new column that is created

Merge the **MasterTable** into this one, left outer join, using the Resource Name column to match

Expand the capacity column using the arrows atop the new column that is created

Add column... custom column .. that divides capacity by count. Remove extra columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"RESOURCE NAME", type text}, {"SKILL GROUP", type text}, {"PROJECT", type text}, {"DEMAND", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"RESOURCE NAME"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"Data", each _, type table}}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data", {"SKILL GROUP", "PROJECT", "DEMAND"}, {"SKILL GROUP", "PROJECT", "DEMAND"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Data",{"RESOURCE NAME"},MasterTable,{"RESOURCE NAME"},"MasterTable",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded MasterTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "MasterTable", {"CAPACITY"}, {"FULLCAPACITY"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded MasterTable", "Capacity", each [FULLCAPACITY]/[Count]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Count", "FULLCAPACITY"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

output from slightly different input to show decimals

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate these lines, not able to understand 

Expand the data using the arrows atop the column - //I am not seeing this option, I can three columns (Resource Name, Count & Data)

Merge the other table into this one, left outer join, using the Resource Name column to match - // Which table you mean master table with Reference Table? 

Expand the capacity column - //You mean in the master table?

Add custom column that divides capacity by count. //So code above given will be used?

Comment: Load the first table as explained. Load the data for second table. use home ... advanced and paste in my code, replacing my let source row with yours. then just step along the code and look at the results of the steps